# Sendgrid throwing error The from object must be provided for every email send

Tags: java, sendgrid

```
{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"<EMAIL>"}],"from":{"name":"ABCD","email":"<EMAIL>"},"subject":"Verify OTP","custom_args":{"OTP":"dsgsdf"}}],"template_id":"<TEMPLATE_ID>"}
```

{{"errors":[{"message":"The from object must be provided for every email send. It is an object that requires the email parameter, but may also contain a name parameter.  e.g. {"email" : "example@example.com"}  or {"email" : "example@example.com", "name" : "Example Recipient"}.","field":"from.email","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.from"}]}

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendEmail(String otp, String email, String toName) {
        Email from = new Email();
        from.setEmail(sendgridFrom);
        from.setName(fromName);
        String subject = "Verify OTP";
        Email to = new Email();
        to.setName(toName);
        to.setEmail(email);
        DynamicTemplatePersonalization personalization = new DynamicTemplatePersonalization();
        personalization.addTo(to);
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom(from);
        personalization.setSubject(subject);
        personalization.addDynamicTemplateData("OTP", otp);
        mail.addPersonalization(personalization);
        mail.setTemplateId(sendgridTemplate);
        SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(sendgridApiKey);
        Request request = new Request();
        try {
            request.setMethod(Method.POST);
            request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
            request.setBody(mail.build());
            Response response = sg.api(request);
            int currentIndexCount = 0;
            int status = response.getStatusCode();
            while (status != 202 && currentIndexCount < maxEmailRetries) {
                response = sg.api(request);
                status = response.getStatusCode();
                currentIndexCount++;
            }
            log.debug(subject, response.getStatusCode());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class DynamicTemplatePersonalization extends Personalization {

        @JsonProperty(value = "dynamic_template_data")
        private Map<String, Object> dynamic_template_data;

        @JsonProperty("dynamic_template_data")
        public Map<String, Object> getDynamicTemplateData() {
            if (dynamic_template_data == null) {
                return Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap();
            }
            return dynamic_template_data;
        }

        public void addDynamicTemplateData(String key, String value) {
            if (dynamic_template_data == null) {
                dynamic_template_data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                dynamic_template_data.put(key, value);
            } else {
                dynamic_template_data.put(key, value);
            }
        }

    }
```

This code worked for me.